# Not a directory: /usr/deploy/uploads/: MultipartRequest error

Tags: jsp, servlets, upload

I am working with jsp-servlet, I want to upload a file and my server saves that file, I use MultipartRequest to do this, but saveDirectory can't find the directory path in server, even though server already this directory exists
MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, "/usr/deploy/uploads/", 1024 * 1024 * 5, "UTF-8", new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbBHi.png)

I tried path like this and also not working..
MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, "uploads/", 1024 * 1024 * 5, "UTF-8", new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
maybe it will help. this is my web link: http://192.168.1.123/lab/business/busi-trang-chu.jsp